# OOP - best approach for adding property to class

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

We develop an HR application written in Java and mapped with Hibernate; one of the feature is the phase of recruiting.

The `Candidate` class is modeled like this:

```
public class Candidate  {
    private String id;
    private Integer candidateCode;
    private GregorianCalendar birthDate;
    private String italianFiscalCode; //unique code for italian people 
}
```

Since we developed for a market only till now the code is very dependent on a particular legislation, look at the `fiscalCode` class property.

The request is that we generalize this concept to be able to expand to other markets, where for example the unique identifier can be different, can be composed of several strings or be absent at all.

First thing that popped in my mind:

**1 - Simply rename the field as countryIdentifier and add other fields if needed for particular countries.**

```
private String countryIdentifier; //general unique code
private Integer greekAddedCode;
```

This means refactoring the code where needed (all the placed where the old italianFiscalCode gets used), renaming a DBMS column (and adding others eventually) and modifying all the queries that use that field.

This looks like a poor implementation to me

**2 - Subclass `Candidate` creating `ItalianCandidate` and `GreekCandidate` and move the particular field in the subclasses.**

The problem is that the `Candidate` class is already subclassed by `HeavyCandidate` that has the sole function to optimize the Hibernate mapping since we move all the "heavy" properties (many-to-ones and sets) in the heavy class  (this is an approach that we follow with all our beans).

In this situation what is the most correct approach?

Comment: "_The problem is that the `Candidate` class is already subclassed by `HeavyCandidate`_". No. `Candidate` should have a field of type `HeavyCandidate` - this is not an _is a_ relationship. Your current approach is a gross abuse of inheritance and an excellent example of why inheritance should not be abused in this way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @BoristheSpider. I guess this approach was made to be able to map easily the beans through Hibernate, but I agree it's not the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an interface `Identifier` (not sure about the name) that is implemented by classes like `GreekIdentifier` and `ItalianIdentifier`. Then I'd add a field to `Candidate`:

```
Identifier identifier;
```

The implementation of `GreekIdentifier` would then look something like this:

```
public class GreekIdentifier implements Identifier {
    String countryIdentifier;
    int addedCode;

    //constructor, getters, setters ...
    //actual behaviour, Indentifier @Overrides ...
}
```

If `countryIdentifier` is really something that all Identifiers have, you can even move it up to an (abstract) base class.

Comment: What does (any methods) Identifier contain ? or is it just marker interface ?

Comment: It would contain any behavior that is common to all Identifiers. What is the end result? What do you want to do with this information? What _is_ an identifier? I don't really know anything about countryIdentifiers and codes...

Comment: Thanks Todd, I think it's a more correct approach that avoid the problem of the Cadidate subclassing. The point is at that point I should make a separate table to store the Identifiers, and I'm sure that the added join for retrieving data would be a drawback.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good way to do this is to make an abstract class. By using this, it will provide a generic framework for each candidate object, and also implies that specific methods need to be in the extending classes. This will also work with constructors, and it is a good way to make a generic outline

```
public abstract class Candidate{
    //Use Vars Here
    private String name;

    //Constructor for the abstract class
    public Candidate(String n){
        //Add Normal Constructor Code Here
        name = n;
    }

    //A possible abstract method that may vary based on the type of candidate
    public abstract String getType();   //Abstract Methods must be defined in a child class
}


public class SpecificCandidate extends Candidate{
    //Add other needed vars
    //Normal Constructor
    public SpecificCandidate(String n){
        super(n);        //This gets passed into the abstract constructor
    }

    //Define the Abstract Method
    @Override
    public String getName(){
        return "Specific";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing that can be done according to me is to extend the Class and create the subclasses.

Then what you can do is add the required fields to that classes.

So

```
public class YourCandidate extends Candidate{

   // extra fields
}
```

Create a separate table for the relation mapping between Candidate and other GreekCandidates.

By adopting this:

1. You would prevent duplication of code.
2. You would stick to the main principles of OOP and maintain a hierarchy. This can be a good [example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritence-table-per-hierarchy-mapping/).
3. *That way you won't have to modify the current class and tables.*, which is always a good thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm going to read the article linked, do you have any advice for the fact that the class is already subclassed?

Comment: @frankieta I guess you can then extend that subclass for all the countries that will need to have the subclass.

Comment: Do you mean extending HeavyCandidate then? That class loads way too much data that is not primary information compared to the Identifier field.